# Meteor rendered and mongodb collection

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

Am new to Meteor. I am trying to display data from mongoDB collection and want to iterate it to perform some calculation.

As mentioned bellow:

```
Employee = new Mongo.Collection("data");

Template.welcome.rendered = function() {
   var employee = Employee.find({}); 
   employee.forEach(function(emp){ console.log(emp.id); });
}
```

But am getting an empty array. How to handle this situation?

(I can put it on 'helper and subscriber portion', but I need to perform some jQuery operation using embedly. But this jQuery not working in this helper function.)

Comment: You should probably wait for your subscription to be done before you render welcome template. Maybe there is no data yet in Employee collection when it's rendered

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But the collection have data.
But the find() does not working with render.

Comment: So running Empoyee.find().fetch() returns data in rendered function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should know that when you declare Mongo collection is better to use the same name "employee" in the constructor.

Also you should notice that in with the latest version of MeteorJS you should use **Template.name.onRendered()** instead of **rendered** which works for backward compatibility but it will be deprecated.

One more thing. Don't forget about the underscore before id like this: **_id**

Try this code and see if it works:

```
Employee = new Mongo.Collection("employee");

Template.welcome.onRendered( function() {
   var employee = Employee.find({}); 
   employee.forEach(function(emp){ console.log(emp._id); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
But the solution is not working with db fetch.
And as you mention like that "onRendered() " is deprecated.

Is there is any other way in meteor to fetch data from db and also peform JQuery operation ?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working with db fetch? Are you sure you publish the collection to the client?

Answer (score 0):

The meteor docs say that

> On the client, there will be a period of time between when the page loads and when the published data arrives from the server during which your client-side collections will be empty.

Source: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find

Comment: Try to remove autopublish using
meteor remove autopublish

add publish on server side

Meteor.publish('tasks',function(){
  return Tasks.find({});
});

And add subscribe on the client side 

Template.todos.onRendered(() => {

    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
    const tasksArr = Tasks.find({}).fetch();
    
});

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove autopublish using
`meteor remove autopublish`.

Add publish on server side:

```
Meteor.publish('tasks',function(){
  return Tasks.find({});
});
```

And add subscribe on the client side:

```
Template.todos.onRendered(() => {

    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
    const tasksArr = Tasks.find({}).fetch();
    
});
```

If you use Iron Route, use

```
Router.route('/todos', {
    waitOn: function (){
        return Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
    },
    action: function (){
        this.render('todos_calendar');
    }
});
```

This tutorial may be helpful: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe